# sql - Return records when a field count is greater than day before

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using sql server and with a table(players) that contains the following data(08/05/2016 is current date):

```
date         player  sport      games
08/05/2016   max     soccer     8
08/05/2016   steve   baseball   8
08/05/2016   max     football   6
08/05/2016   max     ping pong  5
08/04/2016   steve   baseball   4
08/04/2016   max     soccer     3
08/04/2016   max     football   8
```

I am trying to get the results when a player plays more games by sport compared to previous day.

I want to create output with the date, player, sport and more_games when a player played more games for a particular sport compared to previous day, so that a query result on above table would look like this:

```
date         player  sport    more_games
08/05/2016   max     soccer       5
08/05/2016   steve   baseball     4 
08/05/2016   max     ping pong    5
```

**note: not showing records where games were less than previous day, or not played at all, but showing records when game was played today but not yesterday.

I have the following selects:

(---to get records from current date---)

```
Select date, player, sport, games from players where date=getdate()
```

(---to get records from previous date---)

```
Select date, player, sport, games from players where date=dateadd(d, -1,getdate())
```

I just don't how to compare the two Selects and put into final result set.  I was thinking of aliasing each Select then compare records.  Could use a little help.  Thank you.

Comment: So, not really anything to do with MySQL?

Comment: you can't be using both mysql and sql-server, please pick one.

Comment: While it is possible to give an answer with a self-join that works on both databases, SQL Server has windowing functions like `LAG` that allow you to compare one row with the previous one without performing a self-join. The result is both cleaner and faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       select x.dateplay as [date], x.players,x.game as Sports, (x.score -isnull(y.score,0)) as more_games
       from
       (SELECT     dateplay, players, game, score,  convert(varchar,dateplay,101) as exp1
        FROM         dbo.players
        where convert(varchar,dateplay,101) = convert(varchar,getdate(),101)) x left outer join 
       (
       SELECT     dateplay, players, game, score, convert(varchar,dateplay,101) as exp1
       FROM         dbo.players
       where convert(varchar,dateplay,101) = convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),101)
       ) y on x.players =y.players and x.game = y.game -- and  x.score > y.score
       where   (x.score- isnull(y.score, 0))>=0
```

try this code, it works fine in SQL

Answer (score 0):

So from what you said this gives us all players and the number of games they played by date.

```
Select base.date, base.player, base.sport, base.games 
from players base
```

Now we join that to the prior day (and check the games is greater)

```
Select base.date, base.player, base.sport, base.games 
from players base
join players prior on base.player = prior.player 
                  and base.sport = prior.sport
                  and base.date = dateadd(day,1,prior.date)
where base.games > prior.games
```

If you just want today then add

```
  and base.date = getdate()
```

Note I used sql server dateadd since you were not clear on your platform and you used it in your example. In mysql you would use `DATE_ADD(prior.date,INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Comment: I appreciate response and will try it.